# How likely is it that 'Einstein spontaneous transition rate" in these papers refers to the rate of spontaneous emission?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, research-level, spectroscopy, ions

In a prior question [I sorta posed the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319513/where-does-this-equation-for-ionic-abundances-come-from-and-what-does-it-mean?noredirect=1#comment717803_319513) "What is the Einstein spontaneous transition rate for the selected line?"

The main question wasn't really focused on it, and (as of writing this) the main question doesn't have any answers. Regardless, I've done a bit more research into the matter, and I now have an understandable definition for something that sounds remarkably similar.

So now I've got from [a number of different papers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319513/where-does-this-equation-for-ionic-abundances-come-from-and-what-does-it-mean?noredirect=1#comment717803_319513) (by the same person):

> $A_{ul}$ is the Einstein spontaneous transition rate for the line

From [this paper](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2005/40/aa2869-05.pdf):

> $A_{jk}$ is the Einstein spontaneous transition rate of the ionic line

Those variables look a lot like the variables for [the Einstein coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients), and there happens to be an [Einstein coefficient for spontaneous emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients#Spontaneous_emission), and there happens to be some nice equations for [the rate of spontaneous emission in free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission#Rate_of_spontaneous_emission).

Are the Einstein spontaneous transition rate and the rate of spontaneous emission the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I'm 95% sure those are the same thing.  Try to find some papers by different authors that you can cross-reference with (sometimes individual authors have strange/different conventions, or even propagated errors; at the very least different authors will present things in different ways which can really help to understand it).

Comment: I agree with @DilithiumMatrix, it looks very likely that it is the same thing they are talking about. EDIT: Seeing your original questions, my belief has grown to almost certainty. It looks exactly like the kind of systems I have been working on for most of my Ph.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* define the Einstein A coefficient as the spontaneous emission rate. It has units of s$^{-1}$ and so is the rate of spontaneous emission per atom in the upper level.

On the other hand you could also argue that in a quantity of material that the spontaneous emission rate is the number of spontaneously emitted photons per second. In which case you would have to multiply the Einstein A coefficient by the number of atoms that are in the upper level.

The rate of spontaneous emission defined in the wikipedia page you reference *is* defined as being equivalent to the Einstein A coefficient ([about three paragraphs earlier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission#Introduction)).